# jquery sortable ui remove item when is dragged to a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using [jQuery sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) plugin

I have two blocks connected one is draggable and the other is only sortable.

What I want to do is when I'm dragging an item from the sortable in to a specific div to remove it.

Here's the markup:

```
  <div>Draggable source items
    <ul>
        <li class="draggable" class="ui-state-highlight">Drag me down</li>
        <li class="draggable" class="ui-state-highlight">Drag me down 2</li>
        <li class="draggable" class="ui-state-highlight">Drag me down 2</li>

    </ul>
</div>

<div>Sortable List 1
    <ul class="sortableList">

    </ul>
</div>

<div class="test">
     <!--IF YOU DRAG THE ITEM fROM THE SORTABLE LIST HERE IT WILL REMOVE IT -->
</div>
```

JS:

```
   (document).ready(function () {
    $(".sortableList").sortable({
        revert: true,
        /*update: function (event, ui) {
            // Some code to prevent duplicates
        }*/
    });
    $(".draggable").draggable({
        connectToSortable: '.sortableList',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        helper: 'clone',
        revert: 'invalid'
    });
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LMGg8/8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this?

```
$('.droppableArea').droppable({
    accept: 'li',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.helper.remove();
    }
});
```

I marked your droppable DIV with 'droppableArea' class. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LMGg8/10/) for details.